# binary logistic regression - Model Fit Problem

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data

I have a run a binary logistic regression to identify associations between three categorical variables (gender, work sector, workplace region/location) and violence victimisation at work. Sample size= approx 20,000 participants

I have significant terms, but the goodness of fit tests indicates the model may not be appropriate. Hosmer and Lemeshow p<0.05.

Does this mean I should exclude these results from my analysis? If not, how can I justify their inclusion?

Results:

Omnibus Tests of Model Coefficients

|  |  | Chi-sq | df | Sig. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Step 1 | Step | 130.979 | 9 | .000 |
|  | Block | 130.979 | 9 | .000 |
|  | Model | 130.979 | 9 | .000 |

Model Summary

| Step 1 | -2 Log likelihood | Cox & Snell R Square | Nagelkerke R Square |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 23676.753a | .007 | .010 |

a Estimation terminated at iteration number 3 because parameter estimates changed by less than .001.

Hosmer and Lemeshow Test

|  | Chi-sq | df | Sig. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Step 1 | 46.123 | 8 | .000 |

|  | B | SE | Wald | df | sig | exp(b) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gender(1) | .085 | .031 | 7.423 | 1 | .006 | 1.089 |
| Geolocation |  |  | 82.585 | 4 | .000 |  |
| Geolocation(1) | .293 | .038 | 59.931 | 1 | .000 | 1.340 |
| Geolocation(2) | .240 | .046 | 27.125 | 1 | .000 | 1.272 |
| Geolocation(3) | .318 | .093 | 11.781 | 1 | .001 | 1.374 |
| Geolocation(4) | .370 | .110 | 11.297 | 1 | .001 | 1.448 |
| Sector |  |  | 48.112 | 4 | .000 |  |
| Sector(1) | -.027 | .246 | .012 | 1 | .911 | .973 |
| Sector(2) | .153 | .247 | .386 | 1 | .534 | 1.166 |
| Sector(3) | -.047 | .249 | .036 | 1 | .850 | .954 |
| Sector(4) | .712 | .286 | 6.215 | 1 | .013 | 2.038 |
| Constant | -.529 | .247 | 4.584 | 1 | .032 | .589 |

Comment: I have read the answers in the following threads but am still unsure whether this applies to my question:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50244/interpreting-the-results-of-a-binary-logistic-regression